# suppressing of text fields

Tags: sql

I currently have a basic signature suppression applied to a document, the signature appears when prompted for a pin in the parameter field. If the pin is entered correctly then the signature appears and if input incorrectly then the 'not approved' appears on the document.
I want to add an additional Name to the list which will need an additional pin and the suppression of the 'not approved' field changing.
Pin suppression is:
 {?PIN} <> '1906'
Not approved suppression is:
 {?PIN} = '1906'
how to i add another pin to the this suppression?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com! Please post your code so we can see your problem in more detail.

Comment: Also, which RDBMS are you using? Posting table structures and some test data will give you more opportunities to have some answer. You can use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) for these purposes.